# Is there a name for Lie superalgebras which are generated by the odd subspace?

Tags: terminology, lie-superalgebras

Every Lie superalgebra $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{g}_{\bar 0} \oplus \mathfrak{g}_{\bar 1}$ has a canonical ideal $\mathfrak{k} = [\mathfrak{g}_{\bar 1},  \mathfrak{g}_{\bar 1}] \oplus \mathfrak{g}_{\bar 1}$, generated by the odd subspace $\mathfrak{g}_{\bar 1}$.

Is there an accepted name for Lie superalgebras for which this ideal is not proper? i.e., for which $\mathfrak{k} = \mathfrak{g}$?  In [a previous paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.5034) I called them *odd-generated* but I am wondering whether there is an alternative accepted nomenclature.